# CLT for a converging array of random variables

Tags: limits-and-convergence

Assuming that  for each fixed $k$, $(X_{n,1},\ldots,X_{n,k})\Longrightarrow(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ are i.i.d. with mean zero and variance  $\sigma^2$, will the array inherit the CLT from its limit? i.e. do I have (if $r_n\to\infty$):
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_n}}(X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,r_{n}})\Longrightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: You haven't said that each of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ is normally distributed. Did you intend that to be understood? If so, it should be mentioned.

Comment: It is not generally true that if $U,V$ are normally distributed then so is $U+V.$ For example, let $V=\pm U,$ where $\text{“$\pm$”}$ it is $\text{“$+$”}$ with probability $1/2$ and otherwise $\text{“$-$”},$ independently of $U.$ Then $\Pr(U+V=0)>0$ and $\Pr(U+V\ne0)>0,$ so this sum is not normally distributed. $\qquad$

Comment: None of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ has actually to be  normally distributed let alone jointly. But since they are i.i.d. they will satisfy CLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Take any sequence $r_n \to \infty$ and let $X_{n,k}$ be iid  $N(0,1)$ for $k \ne r_n$, and $X_{n,r_n} = r_n$.  The hypothesis is satisfied because $(X_{n,1}, \dots, X_{n,k})$ are iid $N(0,1)$ as soon as $n$ is so large that $r_n > k$.  But
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_n}}(X_{n,1} + \dots + X_{n,r_n}) \sim N(\sqrt{r_n}, \frac{r_n-1}{r_n})$$
which is not even tight.

Comment: sorry. I forgot to say that $r_n=o(n)$.

Comment: @mdou: The same idea still works, see edit.

Comment: I see. Excellent. Thank you very much for this answer.